# How could I get text from THREE.TextGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created new `Mesh` from `TextGeometry` and pushed it into mesh array:

```
var text3d = new THREE.TextGeometry( "Hello!", {
    font: "hevletiker"
});
text3d.computeBoundingBox();
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xb0bca7, overdraw: true });
meshArray.push(new THREE.Mesh( text3d, textMaterial ));
```

So, my questions are:

1. How could I get original text from `text3d` object?
2. How could I get same text from Mesh object (which is contained in meshArray)?

I didn't find anything helpful in [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/57/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

THREE.TextGeometry  converts the text to shapes right away, and does not store the original text anywhere. There is no way to get it afterwards.

You are of course free to bind a variable to text3d yourself, like any object in javascript.

```
var mytext = "Hello!";
var text3d = new THREE.TextGeometry(mytext, {
    font: "hevletiker"
});
text3d.text = mytext; // storing this for later use...
text3d.computeBoundingBox();
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xb0bca7, overdraw: true });
meshArray.push(new THREE.Mesh( text3d, textMaterial ));
```

If you do this, you can later read the text with `text3d.text` or from the Mesh with `mesh.geometry.text` or `meshArray[xxx].geometry.text`

Comment: Could you explain how to change the text please? I tried to read `text3dItem.geometry.text` (where text3dItem is my mesh: `var text3dItem = new THREE.Mesh(text3d_volume, material); `) ... Or should I open a new question for this?

Comment: @zvdh I could not set the text during runtime. I have reported this issue 5 min ago in the project's repository: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4324

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV Yes, at the moment removing text and creating new is the way to go. Changing the text at runtime is not supported. Your suggestion of adding setText() or other way to change the text makes sense though. Wouldn't be much more efficient than just recreating the text yourself though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am glad to have found a solution. For other readers, please see [post in github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4324)